# Objective-C: iPhone app Thread 1 signal SIGABRT

Tags: objective-c, sigabrt

I'm new to *objective-c* and I've gone through a tutorial to build a **'tip calculator'** app for *iPhone*. I'm using *Xcode 4.3.3* and I have checked all the code and it is identical to that in the tutorial (which I'm sure is correct). I have been trawling through site trying to find someone who had the same problem and I have not been able to fix it so I appreciate any help. This is the message that appears whenever I try to run the app.

> 2012-07-23 14:22:01.021 Tip_Calculator[554:f803] -[ViewController
>   initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x68a3130
>   2012-07-23 14:22:01.025 Tip_Calculator[554:f803] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[ViewController initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x68a3130'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x13c8022 0x1559cd6 0x13c9cbd 0x132eed0 0x132ecb2 0x234135 0x333c6e 0x333383 0x233cad 0x333c6e 0x33367b
>   0x333383 0x233105 0x43ceef 0x43d03e 0x11d7a 0x11ff8 0x1117f 0x20183
>   0x20c38 0x14634 0x12b2ef5 0x139c195 0x1300ff2 0x12ff8da 0x12fed84
>   0x12fec9b 0x10c65 0x12626 0x253d 0x24a5) terminate called throwing an
>   exception(lldb)

This is the area flagged in *main.m*:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
@autoreleasepool {        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil,     NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));    }
}
```

I have checked all the interface connections and they are fine. I have also added an exception breakpoint and this error showed up :

> 2012-07-23 20:49:53.633 Tip_Calculator[2067:f803] -[ViewController
>   initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x68c09c0
>   (lldb)

This is the error log that is shown:

```
Tip_Calculator`start:
0x2470:  pushl  $0
0x2472:  movl   %esp, %ebp
0x2474:  andl   $-16, %esp
0x2477:  subl   $16, %esp
0x247a:  movl   4(%ebp), %ebx
0x247d:  movl   %ebx, (%esp)
0x2480:  leal   8(%ebp), %ecx
0x2483:  movl   %ecx, 4(%esp)
0x2487:  addl   $1, %ebx
0x248a:  shll   $2, %ebx
0x248d:  addl   %ecx, %ebx
0x248f:  movl   %ebx, 8(%esp)
0x2493:  movl   (%ebx), %eax
0x2495:  addl   $4, %ebx
0x2498:  testl  %eax, %eax
0x249a:  jne    0x00002493               ; start + 35
0x249c:  movl   %ebx, 12(%esp)
0x24a0:  calll  0x000024b0               ; main at main.m:14
**0x24a5:  movl   %eax, (%esp)**
0x24a8:  calll  0x000033ca               ; exit
0x24ad:  hlt    
0x24ae:  nop    
0x24af:  nop
```

I put *asterisks* around the flagged area. The same error is shown whether there is an exception breakpoint or not.

I am using storyboard, here is the `.h` file of the *ViewController*:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : NSObject
{
//outlets
IBOutlet UITextField *billField;

IBOutlet UITextField *tipFieldTen;
IBOutlet UITextField *tipFieldFifteen;
IBOutlet UITextField *tipFieldTwenty;
IBOutlet UITextField *tipFieldCustom;
IBOutlet UITextField *totalFieldTen;
IBOutlet UITextField *totalFieldFifteen;
IBOutlet UITextField *totalFieldTwenty;
IBOutlet UITextField *totalFieldCustom;
IBOutlet UILabel *customPercentLabel;
IBOutlet UISlider *customPercentSlider;

NSString *billTotal;
}
-(IBAction)calculateTip:(id)sender;



@end
```

And here is the *.m* file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)awakeFromNib; 
{
[billField becomeFirstResponder]; //display keyboard for billField
}

-(IBAction)calculateTip:(id)sender
{
static BOOL toggle = YES;

if (toggle)
{
    toggle = NO;
    NSString *billFieldText = billField.text;

    float newTotal = [billFieldText floatValue];
    float customTipPercent = customPercentSlider.value;

    if(sender ==billField)
    {
        if (billFieldText.length <billTotal.length)
            billTotal = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", 
                         newTotal / 10];
        else
            billTotal = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f",
                         newTotal * 10];

        billField.text = billTotal;

        newTotal = [billTotal floatValue];

        float tenTip = newTotal * 0.10;
        float fifteenTip = newTotal * 0.15;
        float twentyTip = newTotal * 0.20;

        tipFieldTen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", tenTip];
        tipFieldFifteen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", fifteenTip];
        tipFieldTwenty.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", twentyTip];

        totalFieldTen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", newTotal + tenTip];
        totalFieldFifteen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", newTotal +   fifteenTip];
        totalFieldTwenty.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", newTotal + twentyTip];
    }
    else if (sender == customPercentSlider)
    {
        int percentage = (int)(customTipPercent * 100);
        customPercentLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i%%", percentage];
        float newSliderValue = ((float) percentage) / 100;
        customPercentSlider.value = newSliderValue;
        customTipPercent = newSliderValue;
    }
    float customTip = customTipPercent * newTotal;
    tipFieldCustom.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", customTip];
    totalFieldCustom.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", customTip + newTotal];
}
else
{
    toggle = YES;
}

}



@end
```

Any help would be much appreciated as I'm new to *objective-c*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have

```
@interface ViewController : NSObject
```

this should probably be:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
```

**Reason:**

So your `ViewController` class is currently inheriting from `NSObject`, which does not implement `initWithCoder`.  In fact, this method call is part of the `NSCoding` protocol, which `UIViewController` adopts.

**Background:**

The error you received is basically saying that an object of the class `ViewController` was sent a selector, or 'message', `initWithCoder`, but it didn't have an implementation of that method.  So there are two things you would generally do to track this down:

1) Check if you are sending that message anywhere in your code, and then whether the object that receives it is of a class that should recognise that method.  You also have to consider that method being called from UIKit, etc frameworks, which makes this a bit more difficult.

2) If the above looks ok, then you have to consider that perhaps while your code assumes an object is one type, it might actually be a different one, hence this error occuring.

Consider this code:

```
NSArray *anArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"aString", nil];
NSNumber *aNumber = [anArray objectAtIndex:0];
BOOL isEqual = [aNumber isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:42]];
```

This will compile without warning, but when run will cause an exception - because it assumes the object in the array is `NSNumber`, but in fact it is `NSString`:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString
>   isEqualToNumber:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6cbfc'

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response! I am beginning to understand the problem and the reasoning behind it thanks to your explanation

Comment: No worries - there are a whole bunch of concepts that you have to learn when learning Objective-C.  In this case, reading up on protocols!